# Using LEAD Function and do deduct calculation in one SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having Lead function and doing calculation(deduct) in ONE select statement instead of using nested select statement to achieve the results

Below shows my current not working sql statement. CurrentDate - Nxcurrentdate and having a column with showing the difference:

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   CURRENTDATE,
   LEAD(CURRENTDATE,1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY  ID, CURRENTDATE ) NX_DATE,
   NX_DATE - CURRENTDATE AS DATE_DIFF 
FROM TABLEA
```

Expected results should be:

```
   ID   CurrentDate   NxDate    DateDiff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `datediff(interval, date1, date2)` and `getdate()`

```
Select *, DATEDIFF(day, t1.CURRENTDATE, t1.NX_DATE) AS DATE_DIFF) from (
    SELECT 
    ID, getdate() as CURRENTDATE,
    LEAD(getdate(),1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY  ID, getdate()) NX_DATE
FROM TABLEA) t1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is working but i realized that the execution duration is slightly longer to perform.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
SELECT 
  ID, CURRENTDATE,
  LEAD(CURRENTDATE,1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, CURRENTDATE ) NX_DATE,
  datediff(day,CURRENTDATE,LEAD(CURRENTDATE,1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, CURRENTDATE)) AS DATE_DIFF
from tablename
```